# For tower fields, am I allowed to use the modulo equations recursively?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

If I build up $\mathbb F_{q^4}\cong\mathbb F_{q^2}[Y]/(Y^2-X)$ on $\mathbb F_{q^2}\cong \mathbb F_q[X]/(X^2+1)$ am I allowed to use $-1 = X^2 = Y^4$? I do not see any reason or rule, that would be critical here.

Comment: Sure.  Sometimes it's a little clearer when dealing with elements of a field to say something like let $\alpha$ be a root of $X^2+1$ and then $\beta$ a root of $Y^2-\alpha$, so $\beta^4 = \alpha^2=-1$  If you want to deal with the polymods better to say $Y^4+1\in (Y^2-X)$

Answer (score 1):

There is the following problem in your construction. Not necessarily in the notation (I endorse sharding4's comment), but in thinking that you get a field of order $q^4$ this way. This is not really your main question - just something I wanted to explain.

Your $X$ (or its coset) would be an element of multiplicative order $4$. This will, indeed, give you a quadratic extension of $\Bbb{F}_q$ **provided that it did not contain a fourth root of unity already.** In other words, for this to work you need $q\equiv-1\pmod4$. Also observe that if $q$ is even, then $X^2+1=(X+1)^2$.

But, at that point your luck runs out. You won't get $\Bbb{F}_{q^4}$ by adjoining an eighth root of unity (your $Y$). This is because $8\mid q^2-1$ for all odd $q$. As $\Bbb{F}_{q^2}^*$ is cyclic this means that it will already contain primitive eighth roots of unity. In other words, $Y^2-X$ will never be irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_q(X)$.

Comment: Do you mean, that $Y^2-X$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb F_q[X]$ in case of $q\equiv 3\ \bmod\ 4$?

I just found out, that $-1$ is only a non-square in this case. Therefore, $\mathbb F_q[X]/(X^2+1)$ is only in that case a field.

Comment: Correct @Shalec. $X$ is a square in $\Bbb{F}_{q^2}$.